# VS2010 and DSL deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dsl

Can anybody help me on this? I want some guide on how to deploy DSL in vs2010, i use the VSIX output that is in DSLPackageProject\Bin\Debug but when then i want to add that item to some project(File->Add New Item) it just adds dsl but without any DSL functionality that is available in experimental hive,

Many Thanks,
Hrayr

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the Beta 1 of Visual Studio, if you install the Beta 2 you will be able to deploy your DSL correctly